# ROR: Dynamic Select Boxes, jQuery not working or code error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

i'm trying to implement a dynamic select menu whereby the user chooses a subject and then a list of students in that subject will appear in the dropdown afterward. Clearly I have done something wrong. I suspect jQuery might not be working in my application. I am using Rails 4.2

View:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :classmodule %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select :subject_type, Classmodule.order(:subject), :id, :subject, include_blank: true %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :studentname %><br>
  <%= f.grouped_collection_select :studentname, Classmodule.order(:subject), :students, :subject, :id, :s_alias, include_blank: true %>
</div>
```

Associations:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :classmodule
    belongs_to :student

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :notes
    belongs_to :classmodule
end

class Classmodule < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :notes
    has_many :students
end
```

Just to explain that the form is for the notes table.

My jQuery (I follow railscast 88). I'm fresh at this so forgive me if I missed something silly here! Notes.coffee:

```
jQuery -> 
   students = $('#note_studentname').html()
   $('#note_subect_type').change ->
     classmodule = $('#note_subject_type :selected').text()
     options = $(students).filter("optgroup[label='#{classmodule}']").html()
     if options 
      $('#note_studentname').html(options)
     else
      $('#note_studentname').empty()
```

I'm not sure how much information I need to give. Schema

```
create_table "classmodules", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
    t.string   "subject"
    t.integer  "classmodule_id"
  end

 create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "student_id"
    t.string   "student_forename"
    t.string   "student_surname"
    t.string   "s_alias"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.integer  "classmodule_id"
  end

Application.js:

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs   
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require list
//= require list.fuzzysearch
//= require_tree .

Application.html.erb


<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=raleway:400, 700' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <link href="styles/ihover.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
```

The page shows up fine but nothing happens on selecting from the first dropdown.

Appreciate any advice if anyone spots something I did wrong in jQuery or elsewhere! My worry is jQuery might not be working for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: Your Rails code doesn't know about your jQuery code from what I can tell.

Comment: That's my suspicion but I could have coded it wrong too. Is there anything I could try to get jQuery working? Something in the app must be interfering.

Comment: watch this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript

Comment: Yeah the first part of that, the pop up, is not working. So I guess that means jQuery is not working on my site.

Answer (score 0):

Forget I asked, I just got it working. Use id is best approach. :D Everything the same but with id instead. I feel so silly.